# Windows domains and trust relationship error on vmware spapshots vm's

Tags: automation, subdomain, virtual-machine, snapshot, psexec

I'm working on automation, where we use lots of vmware vm's. About year ago we were asked to move all the vm's on the domain from the workgroups. Usually for each automation run we revert that vm back to the snapshot, power it on, then run branch of stuff through Jenkins remotely on those vm's using PSExec.

The problem is that every once in a while PSExec would return complaining about 
The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

The workaround is to remove vm's back from domain to the work-group, restart it, put back on domain, recreate a snapshot.. It adds up when you have 20 of those.

I spoke to our sysadmins and they have no clue what it could be and why would we get this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve that? I'm facing the same problem..